# Rails not booting, nothing in the logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just moved a working copy of a rails 3 app from a test server to a staging server.

I'm getting the standard error screen "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

However, my development.log file has nothing added to it (the migration logs went in fine).

I've doubled checked my settings, everything's fine.

If I make a dummy rails application it works as it should.

EDIT: I'm using Passenger on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: did you check your apache logs? Usually you can get a good hint in there. I suspect it is a permissions issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under the impression that "We're sorry, but something went wrong." was used in the default production environment.  Are the messages being logged to production.log?

As a note, I believe Passenger will launch the application in the production environment by default (as opposed to development environment).

Comment: That worked perfectly, followed these instructions to set it http://my.opera.com/williamn/blog/2009/03/03/how-to-make-phusion-passenger-run-in-development-mode